# Android Hardware Name

Tags: android, wifi, hardware

Is there a way to get the name of the wireless hardware on the phone.  For instance on the Moto Atrix it is eth0.  This is different on other devices however and I need to know what its name is per device.  Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method call

```
    NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
```

will return you an `Enumeration` of `NetworkInterface` objects.
Then you can compare the MAC address of the NetworkInterface (`getHardwareAddress()`)
with the MAC address of your WifiInfo:

```
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    String mac = info.getMacAddress();
```

If you want to know how to compare the String with the byte array, then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797430/formatting-mac-address-byte-array-to-string).

Comment: Yep I have this, but how can I determine that the device is for sure wireless.  I understand the OS will filter out everything except the loopback and the wireless device.  But is there anything that specifically tells me its wireless?

Comment: When I do the getHadwareAddress its not returning the correct data.  I have converted to a string and it give me random character ?  I'm using API level 10.  Any reason why?